# How can i get any feedback from SpeechSynthesis on Android Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, speech-synthesis

I need to detect progress of speaking.

I've tried

1. SpeechSynthesisUtterance: boundary event
2. SpeechSynthesisUtterance: end event
   Nothing fired.

Looks like quite a regular task however google shows just an official documentation which is not relevant for Android for unknown reasons.